# Django - serving static files from collect_static folder in dev

Tags: django

I'm having troubles figuring out how I can serve my static files from the folder where I collect all static files (for eventually in production have those served from a different server).

My frontend static files are under projectroot/frontend, and the static files folder where they collect is undert projectroot/static

My settings.py files looks like this for the relevant bits:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Then my `urls.py` (the root confs) look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(.....), ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then I run the dev server using `python manager.py runserver`. If I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, then I indeed see all the relevent files collected under projectroot/static.

However, if I remove/rename the original folder (/frontend), then the static files are not served by the dev server, meaning it isn't using the /static folder. Which I would prefer to use even in dev, just because I'd rather catch any random issue right away....

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your django application on a server dev/staging etc, typically you'll have apache or nginx doing that and you can configure `/static/` or what have you to serve your static files from the static collection path.

If you're using `runserver` you're typically running in debug mode and django will [magically] serve static for you & load files from apps rather than collecting it all together in 1 place.

This is done with the following in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView, TemplateView
from django.views.static import serve


urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve),
        re_path(
            r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}
        ),
    ]
```

You might also have django debug toolbar, or error templates that you'd like to be able to test, so you can add these to URLs for local testing like this;

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        path('400/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='400.html')),
        path('403/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='403.html')),
        path('404/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='404.html')),
        path('500/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='500.html')),
        path('502/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='502.html')),
        path('503/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='503.html')),
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve),
        re_path(
            r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}
        ),
    ]

    try:
        import debug_toolbar
        urlpatterns = [
            path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
        ] + urlpatterns
    except ImportError:
        pass
```